# To Update a field in user object of salesforce by using another custom object

Tags: trigger

I would like to know how to update fields in user object when i enter some values into the fields in a custom object. Here i tried using trigger. I have tried by writing a trigger when a value is inserted in custom object fields and get saved then user object field gets updated or user object field is auto populated.

```
trigger userfieldupdate on quota(before insert,before update){
      for(quota q:[select id,Name,quotarevenue_c,user_c from quota__c]){
              for(user u:trigger.new) 
      } 
      if(q.user_c==u.Name) { 
          q.quotarevenue_c=u.quotarevenue; 
      } 
 }
```

Comment: Please post your code (stripped to its essence) and where your specific problem lies

Comment: trigger userfieldupdate on quota(before insert,before update){
for(quota q:[select id,Name,quotarevenue_c,user_c from quota__c])
{
for(user u:trigger.new)
}
if(q.user_c==u.Name)
{
q.quotarevenue_c=u.quotarevenue;
}
}

Comment: This is the trigger i have worked .is there any fault in the trigger .

Comment: Salesforcesupport, I've attempted to update your question with your additional info. Do correct that if I've wrongly formatted it. Updating your question with more information is prefered over posting it somewhat hidden in the comments.

Comment: Salesforcesupport: this trigger can't possibly compile; please provide a trigger that compiles; your friend here is the Apex Developer's Guide

Answer (score 2):

These links should help you start on a trigger.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers.htm

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cO3O4yMv7w

It kinda looks like you have the right idea, but you need to start asking specific questions in order to get good answers.  Take time, and rewrite your requirements.

Also you can refer to this link in order to properly structure your question..
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask

By looking at your Trigger, your question needs to be something like "I have a `Quota` Object  that is being updated, and whenever that `Quota` field is updated, my `User` Object needs to be updated also with the change from `Quota`."

Answer (score 0):

We have used the below trigger to map a field in quota object with a field in user object.

```
trigger quotaupdate on Quota__c(before insert , before update)
{
   set<id> userids= new set<id>();
   for(Quota__c q: Trigger.new)
   {
           userids.add(q.User__c);
   }

   Map<Id, user> usermap = new Map<Id, user>( [select Quota__c from user where id in :userids]);

   list<user> updatelist = new list<user>();
   for(Quota__c qu : trigger.new)
   {
        if(usermap.containskey(qu.User__c))
        {
            user u = new user();
            u.id= qu.User__c;
            u.Quota__c=qu.Quota__c;
            u.Last_Year_Quota__c=qu.Last_Year_Quota__c;
            updatelist.add(u);
        }

   }
       if(!updatelist.isEmpty())
       {
           database.update(updatelist,false);

       }
}
```

Comment: are you answering your own question?  if so, mark as a solution. If this is additional info to the original question, remove it from here and add to the original question